# Getting as an array rather than a DataMapper ORM collection object

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, codeigniter-datamapper

I am using the [DataMapper ORM](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/) in my CodeIgniter project.

The problem I am having is, when I use the following codes:

```
$o = new Object();
$o->get();
```

The `$o` becomes a DataMapper ORM collection object rather than an array.

I know I can still use `foreach` to loop through the collection but other PHP array functions (such as `array_pop`,`array_splice`) still can not be used on it.

I would like to know if there is any function provided by DataMapper ORM to return it as an array.

Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DataMapper's `$o->all` property instead of the `$o->get()` method to return an array.

Comment: $o->All Doesn't return all values if there is related objects.

Comment: Relations are only fetched on the current object. $o->all is an array of objects. If arrays are needed, you can use the Array extension, which introduces the to_array() and all_to_array() methods.